# For which values of p does $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^p}dr$ converge?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I have:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^p}dr\quad p>0$$
Right now I figured the following:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^p}dr=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^p}dr+\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^p}dr$$
For the second integral we use that:
$\frac{r}{(1+r^2)^p}$ behaves at $+\infty$ like $\frac{1}{r^{2p-1}}$ and therefore the second integral's behaviour is similar to:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r^{2p-1}}dr$$
Which converges $\iff2p-1>1\iff p>1$.
My question is how could I approach $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{r}{(1+r^2)^p}dr$

Comment: It converges for all $p$, because $1+r^2$ is strictly positive and continuous at the origin (hence near the origin) so all powers enjoy this property as well.

Comment: You don't need to split the integral because the integrand is a continuous function at $r=0$.

Comment: ${d\over dr}(1+r^2)^{1-p}=2(1-p)r(1+r^2)^{-p}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{r}{\left(1+r^2\right)^p} d r & =-\frac{1}{2(p-1)}\left[\frac{1}{\left(1+r^2\right)^{p-1}}\right]_0^{\infty} \\
& =-\frac{1}{2(p-1)}\left(\lim _{r \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\left(1+r^2\right)^{p-1}}-1\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore
$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{r}{\left(1+r^2\right)^p} d r $ converges if and only if $p-1>0 \Leftrightarrow p>1$.